# When a public university in the US receives an industry grant or gift funding, is that information publicly accessible?

Tags: united-states, funding, industry

By "that information", I mean the fact that a firm gave some money to a public university, and perhaps also the amount. If it is publicly accessible, how to access it?

Comment: Maybe. A lot of funding gets channeled through public benefit corporations to evade foi requests. Do you have a specific university system in mind?

Comment: @Libor Thanks, no specific university system in mind. If this makes the question too broad, then let's take the University of California.

Comment: If you have a specific project in mind you could file an open records request, but it would take a couple weeks and you'd have to pay some fees. I don't know of any database or anything.

Comment: @Libor interesting, why would we need a specific project in mind to make such a request? Couldn't we simply request all the funding sources?